# What is/ when to use signInSilently in authorization flows?

Tags: react-native, oauth

There are lots of questions and answers on signInSilently errors, mostly questions about fixing problems with it. But I was not able to find its proper usage, or even reason to use it. This a term used in the google, android and react native ecosystem, and is not limited to the library below.

I am using a react-native library for allowing users to sign in with Google [react-native-google-signin](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-google-signin). This library uses a local cache to store tokens, so the effect of signIn() when the user is already signed is, is also 'silent'. **I don't see the point of signInSilently().**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its more generally know as **Silent Authentication**, and its purpose to refresh/ renew sessions without informing the user. So the user must already be previously logged in for this to succeed.

> to renew sessions in SPAs (single page applications). [source](https://auth0.com/docs/api-auth/tutorials/silent-authentication)

and

> Silent authentication in Azure Active Directory (Azure AD) minimizes
>   the number of times a user needs to enter their login credentials by
>   silently refreshing the authentication token. [source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/tabs/how-to/authentication/auth-silent-aad)